# JavaScript RegExp for optional wrapper and only one remembered part?

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I'd like my RegExp to match both `word` and `[word]` (in fact, some other stuff, but that's not the point), but not `[word` or `word]`. A simple way to do this would be to use the

```
var re = /^(\w+)|(?:\[(\w+)\])$/;
```

RegExp, but depending on which variant has matched, I'll get the `word` either in `match[1]` or `match[2]` (I mean, `var match = re.exec(text);`). My question is: **is it possible to write such a RegExp that it will match what I need but the result will always be in `match[1]` and no other "slot" in `match` is used?**

An example: for "symmetrical" wrapper like `''word''` this can be done using `\1` expression:

```
var re = /^(\'{0,2})(\w+)\1$/;
```

This will match both `''word''` and `word`, but not `''word` or `word''`. But this trick is possible because the opening part of the wrapper is the same as the closing one, which is not the case for `[word]`...

Comment: First, it is not necessary. Second, if you want to hack it a bit, something close to what you need may be used, like [`(?:[^\[]|^)(word(?!\])|\[word])`](https://regex101.com/r/uU6oO3/1), but it will not match `[[word]`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be:

```
var re = /^((?:\[\w+\])|(?:\w+))$/;
```

It filters `[word]` as well as `word` and only fills the first slot of the match.
Tests:

```
re.exec('foo'); // ['foo', 'foo']
re.exec('[foo]'); // ['[foo]', '[foo]']
re.exec('foo]'); // null
re.exec('[foo'); // null
```

Comment: Pardon, may be I'm not clear enough, `match[1]` should contain `word`, not `[word]`, so this doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Ah pardon, than the answer is simple: It's just not possible ;-)

Comment: could you explain why?

Comment: You have to go backwards in the search results, image that the regex parser only goes from one side to the other and has no idea of what was already parsed. There exists some implementations which acually can handle this case, e.g. in Perl http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences but the RegEx of Javascript does not support this interesting feature.

Comment: Maybe you can use something like `re.exec(str.replace(/^\[(\w+)\]$/, '$1'));`

Comment: Ok, in my case it seems the best solution to give up and accept the `word]` and `[word` variants as the whole thing is inside another wrapper, and it's not critical if some "incorrect" stuff will be recognized (as references to articles) -- those will not be another special syntax confused with this (reference) syntax.

Comment: but will you statement remain true if usage of another slot of `match` is permitted? Things like \1 in the example of a "symmetric" wrapper still can't help, right?